# Connection reset error using java mail api in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, email

[image]
Relevant info:-

- I am working on ubutnu , so no firewall issues  i hope.
- I am sitting behind a proxy server.
- I am able to connect to  smtp server through terminal using telnet.
- When I run the same code using gradle from terminal(you need a build tool to download the  java mail api from repository), it works fine.
- I have included the mail api in external jars in my eclipse project and even tried setting/unsetting  the proxy in eclipse, even then it's not working.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error instead of a screenshot, thanks! Makes it more readable for when people search for it in the future!

Comment: You forgot to include the most relevant information: your code.

Comment: I said the same exact same code works fine with gradle..so there is nothing wrong with the code..